# Download manager downloads file as (.bin) [kotlin]

Tags: android, kotlin

I have my source file links on google drive. I have the file links on my project. now I need to force download the file when i click download button. I have used download manager it triggers download but it downloads as (.bin). I my case I cannot give the extension as (.png or .jpg) because the file can be any type it can be (image file, zip file, or 3D files like .obj, .glb) so how can i download as the extension of the original file.

```
private fun downloaad(zipFile: String, title: String) {
        val downloadManager = activity?.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
        val source = Uri.parse(zipFile)
        val request = DownloadManager.Request(source)
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_ONLY_COMPLETION)
        downloadManager.enqueue(request)
        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Downloaded successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

I tried this function it just downloads as .bin

Comment: Yell it where to save the file and under which name.

Comment: did you get solution for that kindly share to how progress the bin file